# double to int conversion warning in std::accumulate

Tags: c++, type-conversion, compiler-warnings

How to force the gcc/clang to show a warning about converting double to int in such code (in particular when using std::accumulate for container of doubles but have result in integer):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<double> v = { 0.5, 0.6, 0.7 };

    // gives wrong result due integer initial value
    std::cout << std::accumulate( v.begin(), v.end(), 0 ) << std::endl; // no warning

    int i = 4.2; // warning

    return 0;
}
```

-Wconversion does not work well. Link: http://goo.gl/efJUou

P.S. VS2013 reports about type deduction warning in template function, by which you can catch the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warnings are disabled by default for system headers. You can use the option [`-Wsystem-headers`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39848b65d9ff745b) to enable them, but the downside is that it will output additional irrelevant warnings.

Comment: If I could have an explanation for the downvote that would be appreciated.